# Server Upgrade issue

Tags: php, centos, apache2.4, apache2.2

Which is the lowest version of centos is supported with php 5.6.12 as i need to update server and i am having centos 5.11.

The response i got from server admin team is that php version 5.6.12 rpm is not available for Centos 5.11 operating system.

If php version 5.6.12 rpm and link is available please share with me.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: this might be better suited to serverfault.com

Answer (score -2):

The difference between apache2.2 and apache2.4 is strictly internal system. deal with purely for administrator system not for developer app.

All the concept and configuration is the same (few change perhaps but not important).

You can migrate easily from apache2.2 to 2.4 with very few issue or working.

*Warning for PHP migrate because it's not the same policy than apache.*

Comment: There are SIGNIFICANT differences between Apache 2.2 and 2.4 requiring a number of config updates: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html

Comment: VERY VERY FEW SIGNIFIANT for me and my 4 complex symfony projects ! Lot of too specific and not common parameter and config. This is a relative and subjective analyse which is too brain teaser. Lot of common project switch from apache2.2 to 2.4 easily and speedly sorry